# Mantras to concentrate on studies

Tags: mantras

Which mantras will help to concentrate.

Sometimes it's difficult to concentrate or focus on a particular thing. Our mind always get deviated. How to avoid this.

Comment: Use pranava bija as short mantra. Try to focus on ajna chakra. Write somewhere: those 2 weeks will pass, after those two weeks I'll be free to enjoy other activities, but I must be ready for my exams. focus to succeed. Something like that. and btw, no internet those 2 weeks, I see you lose a lot of time on internet, trying to make your phone work in a way etc :))))

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  As @sv. says, personal advice questions are not allowed on this site, so I'm closing your question for the time being.  If you want to eliminate the personal details and make it more general, then it may be more acceptable.

Comment: You can chant the Sri Hayagriva mantra which the best mantra for gaining better concentration, memory and right knowledge. You can check the following link for the mantra http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/mantra-for-better-memory-concentration-brain-power

Comment: There are many mantras for this in the Atharva Veda. Talk to a brahmin priest versed in this veda.

Answer (score 6):

You can chant a simple Saraswati mantra "Om Aim Saraswatyai Namaha" daily at morning 108 times at the least.You should be wearing fresh clothes after having a bath.And do sit facing either north or east while chanting.

Refer to [this](http://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/goddesses/saraswati/108-saraswati-names.html) page for Goddess Saraswati's 108 names.
I have selected 3 of these names to support my answer,viz:

> 1)Vidyadhara Supujita(meaning Who is worshiped by Knowledge
>   holders/seekers or students)
>
> 2)Vidyarupa(Who is knowledge personified).That's why students seeking
>   knowledge and education must worship Saraswati to excell in studies.
>
> 3)Mahavidya(The Goddess who has the great knowledge).

Also refer to my [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/why-sarasvati-is-considered-as-goddess-of-knowledge/11050#11050) answer to know how Goddess Saraswati is described in scriptures as the Goddess of knowledge,wisdom & learning.

You can also chant the Panchakshari mantra of Lord Shiva.There is no one better than Parameswara who can help you concentrate your mind better and keep it stay focussed on a particular topic.

Answer (score 0):

Mind gets distracted because of 2 randomly changing entities:

1) **External distractions** from senses that are sound, smell, image, touch etc.,

2) **Internal distractions** that are thoughts based on the previously tasted external distractions by mind to whom some kind of deep emotion is linked like an image of beautiful object, smell of tasty food, sound of a song etc.,

If observed carefully, both becomes prominent on self's mind because self allows them to do so.

[**Pratyahara**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyahara)

When senses and thoughts are pulled towards a point like a dot in center of circle or an image of deity, mind would neither long for anything nor feed on new distractions as there is no time for it do mischief because it is busy on a static source, and hence untamed mind will slowly start settling. Eventually the period between 2 consecutive random thoughts will increase, leading to deeper Dhyana that is the concentration or control of mind. This is a simple definition of pratyahara. Example, doing tratak etc., Remember you are not mind, but master of mind. Pratyahara can also be done on any sound like any mantra etc., Goal is to stop the Ahara(food) of mind.

Comment: He wanted mantras ,and there are mantras for the specific purpose.But your reply is completely wayward and should be downvoted because its of no value in the context.But i haven't done so.

Comment: You mean the method you have suggested is easier to follow than reciting mantras?Ashtanga Yoga ,dhyana,concentration/meditative methods are naturally more difficult for layman & more importantly also to be learnt under a Guru's supervision. So a Guru's involvement  is not exclusive to mantras only.And when he specifically asked for mantras how can my answer be wayward?

Comment: Guru is required to attain Samadhi, pratice Yogasans, Pranayam, getting mantras to reach God etc., which asker is surely not looking for.