# Why Sarasvati is considered as goddess of knowledge?

Tags: belief, saraswati

In Hinduism, Saraswati Devi is often considered as the goddess of knowledge. Also, it is very common practice to celebrate Vasant Panchami festival (the fifth day of spring) in her honour.

Some Hindus celebrate Vasant Panchami and mark the day, by helping young children learn how to write alphabets on that day.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saraswati)

This clearly shows that Saraswati is considered as the goddess of knowledge as per the faith and common practices.

Below is the how Rigveda mentions about her.

> अपो अस्मान मातरः शुन्धयन्तु घर्तेन नो घर्तप्वः पुनन्तु | विश्वं हि
>   रिप्रं परवहन्ति देविरुदिदाभ्यः शुचिरापूत एमि ||

– [Rigveda 10.17](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10017.htm)

**Meaning:**

> May the waters, the mothers, cleanse us, may they who purify with
>   butter, purify us with butter, for these goddesses bear away
>   defilement, I come up out of them pure and cleansed.

***Is there any interesting story/event mentioned in Hindu scripture which leads her to be designated as goddess of knowledge?***

Answer (score 5):

I'll cite from scriptures  to show why Goddess Saraswati is considered as the Goddess of knowledge,wisdom,learning,eloquence,memory , poetic skills etc.

1) The Saraswati Suktam found in Rig Veda 1.3.10 has mentioned(in the last verse of the Suktam) her as the Goddess of learning and eloquence.

[image]

[image]

2) Next is the Saraswati Kavacham found in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.Lord Brahma is the Risi(Seer) of this Kavacha.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**In this Kavacha Goddess Saraswati is identified with the Goddess of speech(Vagdevi),Goddess of Knowledge(Vidyaadhistatri,Vidya Swarupi),One who resides in prose and poetry(Gadya Padya Nivasini) and one who resides as Vidya in sacred books.**

**In Phalasruti too, it is stated that recitation of this Kavacha yields memory power,mental sharpness and immense knowledge.**

3)The last one is another Stuti of Devi Saraswati done by Rishi Yajnavalkya  also to be found in the Brahma Vaivarta Purna.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this stuti too,Goddess saraswati is depicted as the bestower of **Jnana(wisdom)**,**Smriti(memory),Vidya(knowledge) & Kavitwa Shakti(the power of poetry).**

She is also depicted as the **"Adhistatri of all Vidyas"** and as **"Akshara Swarupa"(the Personification of alphabets).**

She is depicted as the embodiment of **Smriti Shakti,Jnana Shakti,Buddhi Shakti and Kalpana Shakti** and **also as the ruler of tongue,mind,thought,speech and anything to do with brains.**

***Conclusion-Goddess Saraswati is considered as the Goddess of Knowledge due to facts that are firmly rooted in our scriptures and not because of beliefs.***

**Edit**-

That Goddess Saraswati is to be worshipped on Sukla Panchami Tithi of the Magha month is mentioned in scriptures.

Mentioned in other Puranas as well but here i'm quoting from the Devi Bhagavatam as found on [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana67.html) page:

> Sage Narayana described the methodology of worship of Devi Sarasvati,
>   the powerful manifestation of Mula Prakriti, the Goddess of Knowledge,
>   Mental Faculties, Memory, ‘Mantras’, Literature and Fine Arts. Her
>   symbol is ‘Veena’ (Lute) and Books; Her ‘Vahana’(Vehicle) is ‘Hamsa’
>   (Swan) and Her male counterpart is Para Brahma. **On every Sukla
>   Panchami of Magha month and on the day of commencing education, the
>   worship of Sarsvati is to be performed as per Kanva Sakha Yajur Veda
>   hymns, if possible.**

Comment: i guess the question is not about which scriptures mentioned her as the goddess of wisdom. The Question is WHY? WHY she is called as  goddess of wisdom? Was there any incidence which lead her to be designated so?

Comment: @AADTechnical "This clearly shows that Saraswati is considered as the goddess of knowledge as per the faith and common practices."-This was what you have stated in the question and which  i have proved to be false.Now,regarding the why part-it is because the BrahmaGyani Risihs have mentioned her to be so.Even Lord Brahma has mentioned her to be so.What more reasons one would need?

Answer (score 5):

She was indeed born like that from left half portion of Brahma. Many Puranas such as [Shiva Purana, Matysa Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6793/3500) describes this birth story of Sarasvati. But Brahmavaivartara Purana describes slightly a different version of her birth. It says Sarasvati was born from left part of Dharma who was born from chest of Sri Krishna. Brahmavaivartara Purana is Krishna- centric text and it says Krishna is Supreme Brahman.

> सौतिरुवाच 
>  आाविर्बभूव कन्यैका धर्मस्य वामपाश्र्वतः।
>   मूर्तिमूर्तिमती साक्षाद् द्वितीया कमलालया॥ ५३॥ 
> आविर्बभूव
>   तत्पश्चान्मुखत: परमात्मनः। एका देवी शुक्लवर्णा वीणापुस्तकधारिणी॥५४॥
>   
> कोटिपूर्णेदुशोभाढया शरत्पङ्कजलोचना। वह्निशुद्धांशुकाधाना
>   रत्नभूषणभूषिता॥ ५५ ॥
>
> Then Sauti said : “At that point of time a beautiful girl emerged out
>   of the left part of Dharma who resembled completely with Laksmi. She
>   was known by the name of Mūrti. Thereafter, a female with white
>   complexion emerged out of the mount of the lord, holding a book and a
>   lute. She had the lustre of crores of suns. Her eyes resembled the
>   lotus flowers of the winter season. She had bright costumes and was
>   adorned with the bright gold ornaments.
>
> सस्मिता सुदती श्यामा सुन्दरीणां च सुन्दरी। श्रेष्ठा श्रुतीनां
>   शास्त्राणां विदुषां जननी परा।। ५६ ।। 
> वागाधिष्ठातृदेवी सा
>   कवीनामिष्टदेवता। शुद्धसत्त्वस्वरूपा च शान्तरूपा सरस्वती॥ ५७॥ 
>   गोविन्दपुरतः स्थित्वा जगौ प्रथमतः सुखम्। तन्नामगुणकीर्तिं च वीणया सा
>   ननर्त च।५८।। 
> कृतानि यानि कर्माणि कल्ये कल्ये युगे युगे। तानि
>   सर्वाणि हरिणा तुष्टाव च पुटाञ्जलिः।। ५९ ।।
>
> She wore a serene smile on her face and she had beautiful teeth. She
>   was the damsel of sixteen year’s age. **She was the best of all the
>   beauties in the universe and all the Srutis, Šāstras and the
>   intelligence emerged out of him. She controlled the speech, the
>   goddess, of all the poets, an incarnation of purity and was known as
>   Sarasvati with a peaceful look.** Standing before Krsna, she played on
>   Wind and then danced. She sang in praise of the lord, highlighting all
>   the chief events of his earlier incarnations.

So, Saraswati manifested as Goddess of Knowledge, music, and speech. There's no particular story of acquiring these qualities or skills.

Comment: hmm..I get what you are saying, but I am afraid but this isn't not one would like to hear, that "she somehow manifested as goddess of knowledge...for no good enough reason"

Comment: @WhisperingMonk Why did Brahma manifest as creator and Vishnu as Preserver and Rudra as destroyer. Why did even the Supreme Brahman manifest for the first time? It's the same thing. They are like posts. They are fixed.