# Mantra for better memory, concentration, brain-power

Tags: mantras

Please suggest anyone to do Mantra at home daily for Memory, Concentration and Brain-Power? Since last few months I couldn't remember such a small things in my daily life.

Comment: Chanting Saraswati mantras will help you.Om saraswatyai namaha oR Om Baagdevyai cha vidmahe virinchi patnyai cha Dhimahi tanno vaani prachodayaath etc.If you are acquainted with reading Sanskrit stotras then read saraswati stotram by Rishi Agastya..It starts with the line"Yaa kundendu Tusara hara davala..."

Comment: In Kaliyuga, all Mantras are futile (locked) due to curse. You will have to first unlock the mantra then only the mantra will work.

Comment: @Rohith.: I couldn't understand your comments. Why the mantras are locked and how can I reopen the mantra.

Answer (score 11):

srI: shrI hayagrIva stOtram
srImathE rAmAnujAya nama:
AzhhvAr emperumAnAr jIyar thiruvadigaLE sharaNam

http://acharya.org/sloka/vdesikan/HayagreevaStotram-eng.pdf

|| shrI hayagrIva stOtram ||

shrImAn vEngkaTanAthArya: kavitArkika kEsarI |
vEdAntAchAryavaryO mE sannidhattAm sadA hrudi ||

> **ज्ञानानन्दमयं देवं निर्मलस्फटिकाकृतिम् ।
>  
>   आधारं सर्व विद्यानां हयग्रीवमुपास्महे ।।**
>
> 1.GYAnAnandamayam dEvam nirmalasphaTikAkrutim |
>   AdhAram sarvavidyAnAm hayagrIvam upAsmahE|| 1
>
> **Meaning** : We meditate upon that Supreme One, who has the neck and face of a horse and who is the embodiment of JnAnA (divine Knowledge) and AnandhA (Bliss). He has a divine akaram (body) like a radiant, blemishless Spatikam (Crystal) and is the abode of all VidhyAs (branches of Learning).

This slOka set in the Vedic anushtup meter is the dhyAna slOkam for BhagavAn
HayagrIva.

> 2.Visshudha Vignana Ghana svaroopam
>   Vignyana Visranana baddhadeeksham|
>   DAyanidhim dehabrutham Sharanyam
>   Devam Hayageevamaham prapadhye || 5
>
> **Meaning** :  I seek refuge in Lord HayagrIvA, whose divyAtvam, Suddha Satthva SvarUpam is the embodiment of pure and unalloyed dhivya Jn~Anam. As the overflowing treasure house of DayA, He has taken the sankalpam to bless the chEthanams with His rejuvenating blessings of dhivya JnAnam that will liberate them from the cycles of births and deaths. To fulfill His vow to liberate them from the darkness of ajnAnam, He stands as their beacon light, their sole and
>   final refuge to bless them with dhivya JnAnam. I am also desiring that divine and redeeming dhivya JnAnam and surrender at His lotus feet.
>
> 3.Vilupta mUrdhanya lipi kramANAm
>   surEndra chUDApada lAlitAnAm |
>   tvadamghri rAjIva raja:kaNAnAm
>   bhUyAn prasAdO mayi nAtha bhUyAt || 20
>
> **Meaning** : Oh Lord HayagrIva! It is said that Brahma Deva encodes the lot in one’s life on the skull at the time of birth (Brahma Lipi). The chEthana’s life is laid out in those instructions. Those lipis (aksharams written on the skull) interfere with the pursuit of Moksha Sukham and the performance of Tapas that would qualify one to realize such a ParamAnugraham.The jeeva suffers from the cycles of births and deaths (SamsAram). MokshAnugraham recedes farther and farther. The incomparable power of the sacred dust from Your lotus feet changes however the fate of the Bhaddha jeeva. BrahmA and other DevAs adorn the sacred dust from Your holy feet to overcome their misfortunes. May the power
>   of those dust from Your sacred feet (PaadhAngri rENu) settle permanently on my head, erase the Braham Lipis and bless me with Moksha.
>
> 4.Vakhya mudhram karasirasijaih pustakam Shanka chakre
>   BibhradbinnaSpatikaruchirE pundareekAy nishannaha |
>   Amlanasreeamrutavishadhairamshubhim plAvayan mam 
>   Avirbhuyadanagha mahimA mAnasay vAgadeesaha || 32
>
> **Meaning** : In His beautiful, lotus soft four hands, Lord HayagrIva sports Sudarsanam, Paancha-janyam, JnAna Mudhra and a Book. He is seated on a freshly-blossomed White Lotus and reminds the UpasakAs of the whitest-white fragment of a freshly cleaved spatikam. His lustre never ever fades. There is no limit (boundary) to His blemishless glories. May This Lord of Vidhyais shower on me His nectarine, white and cool rays! May He reside and preside over my hrudhayAkAsam in this manner!

For a more detailed explanation on entire hayagriva stotram with its inner meaning please check the following [link](http://www.sadagopan.org/SundaraSimham/SS004%20-%20Hayagriva%20stotram.pdf)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45182/discussion-on-answer-by-parthasarathy-raghavan-mantra-for-better-memory-concent).

Answer (score 8):

Among Vedic deities Goddess Saraswati is considered as the Goddess of knowledge,wisdom ,learning,eloquence,**memory** and is associated with virtually **any activities which are related to the brain**.

Goddess Saraswati is depicted as the bestower of Jnana(wisdom),**Smriti(memory),Vidya(knowledge)** & Kavitwa Shakti(the power of poetry).

She is also depicted as the "Adhistatri of all Vidyas" and as "Akshara Swarupa"(the Personification of alphabets).

She is depicted as the embodiment of **Smriti Shakti**,**Jnana Shakti,Buddhi Shakti and Kalpana Shakti and also as the ruler of tongue,mind,thought,speech and anything to do with brains.**

The following Kavacha is found in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.Lord Brahma is the seer.**The Phalasruti states reciting the kavacha yields memory power,mental sharpness and immense knowledge**(exactly the things you are looking for).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can also refer to the Saraswati Stuti by Rishi Yajnavalkya given in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/why-sarasvati-is-considered-as-goddess-of-knowledge/11050#11050).

If reciting stotrams is too cumbersome for you then just recite her mantras.Refer to my comment.

**Edit:-** I'm adding yet another stotram that increases wisdom, memory, brain power ,intellect etc.Its called the "Pragnya Vivardana Karthika Stotram"(The stotram that increases Pragnya or wisdom) dedicated to Lord Shanmuga(Karthikeya).

You can learn the stotram from [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Pragya_Vivardhana_Karthikeya_Stotram) page:

> This paryer to Lord Subrahmanya helps one increase their intelligence
>   and wisdom. It is said that even a mentally retarded child would
>   become normal by reciting this prayer. The prayer is taught by Lord
>   Subrahmanya himself and identifies 28 names of Lord Subrahmanya[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG3Iz.jpg).

The Phalasruti(the result obtained on reading the stotra) states that :

> Maha manthra maya neethi mama namanu keerthanam, Maha
>   pragnamavapnothinathra karya vicharana,
>
> Meaning-These names composed by me, If sung, Would make one extremely
>   intelligent.

But having said that,Its Saraswati who is the embodiment of Smriti Shakti,Jnana Shakti etc.If you want to excel in studies or any other work that requires intellectual proficiency then its her to whom you need to pray to.

Comment: Nice Answer & right one too ,Certainly the "Pragnya vivardana stotram" is the right stotra for memory , brain power , consciousness etc. One can Also chant  these two shlokas for the same या देवी सर्वभुतेषु स्मृतिरूपेण संस्थिता । 
नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः ॥

Yaa Devii Sarva-Bhutessu Smrti-Ruupenna Samsthitaa |
Namas-Tasyai Namas-Tasyai Namas-Tasyai Namo Namah |

Comment: And या देवी सर्वभुतेषु बुद्धिरूपेण संस्थिता । 
नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः ॥
Yaa Devii Sarva-Bhutessu Buddhi-Ruupenna Samsthitaa |
Namas-Tasyai Namas-Tasyai Namas-Tasyai Namo Namah ||8||

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes you are right about those  verses and thank you.

Comment: I have a doubt on Kartikeya Stotram. If I'm not wrong, it's from rudrayAmala tantra. But doesn't it require some special Tantrik Diksha to chant something present in any tantra? Please Clarify Rickross ji.

Comment: May not require Diksha but Diksha is always helpful. You can chant the Stotram. If a Stotram does not contain mantras like Swaha and others anyone can chant it. But having Diksha always accelerates the process of achieving results. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thank you! That means having diksha is good but not necessary in this particular stotram. It gives it's effects even without diksha. Isn't it?

Comment: In my view in order to achieve the full potential of a Stotram one needs to be initiated but even without Diksha a whole lot of things can be achieved from a Stotra. Like grace and protection of the deity and even much more. In one Bhuvaneswari Stotra it is explicitly stated for example that the Mother comes for both the initiated and the uninitiated. So reading a Stotram without Diksha should be fine IMO. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Okk.. But I think initiation in the case of Stotras is only for Tantric stotras. In the case of Vedic Stotras, I haven't heard about initiation. I have heard it's opposite, that for the uninitiated people normal prayers and stotras are made. So what you told just now is only for stotras in Tantras isn't it? 

Comment: There is no such thing as Vedic stotras. Stotras are found in Puranas and Tantras also in Itihasa (like MB). So what I have said is valid for all Stotras. One can read them but the full results can be achieved easily if one has been initiated into mantras (Initiation is considered as the first step in spirituality). But chanting them even without initiation is ok IMO. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thank you Rickross ji for giving your views. And by vedic stotras I meant stotras of puranas, etc. only. Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: Ok thanks @LSSJBroly