# Which is the fastest way to increase your intelligence as mentioned in scriptures?

Tags: vedas, shiva, yoga, adi-shankaracharya, meditation

I'd there any methods mentioned in scriptures to increase intelligence

Comment: Does this help you ? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14804/26679