# What mantra should students follow before any examination?

Tags: mantras

If there is any mantra for students who are going to an examination hall for good memory, what is it?

Obviously, the candidate who has studied very well will perform very well. Simultaneously the mantras are very helpful for the students who fear about the examination or some stages (stage fear).

Comment: Gayatri mantra.

Comment: Related or duplicate [Mantras to concentrate on studies](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10277/3500)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one my grandfather made me learn. He advised me to repeat it thrice before any examination or for that matter before any important event in my life.

> Hari Om! Om Raghavo Vijayam Dadyat mamah sita pateh prabuhu

I apologise for not translating it as I am not appraised with it's meaning.

Answer (score 2):

[This Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Slokas_for_solving_various_problems) page lists various short Mantras and Shlokas that are aimed at solving various kinds of day to day problems we might be facing.

For the given purpose it gives the following Shloka:

> **For increase in knowledge , to pass in examination** (this has to be chanted eight times in the morning)
>
> 15.Bhashyathi sarva sashtraani , yechanye niyamaa thadhaa|
>  Aksharanicha sarvaani thwanthu devu namosthuthe||
>
> I salute her who is the goddess of interpretation of all Sastras , As
>   well as other works laying down rules as well as all alphabets.

This may be a prayer to Goddess Saraswati although explicitly nothing is mentioned.